# How can I insert the abstract, acknowledgment, and contribution sections in Roman numerals?

Tags: thesis, report

I am assembling my thesis in biochemistry. It's the first time that I am using latex. I am quite happy and proud that I learned how to use it (basics). Thank you to the community for helping me (and online videos! :D I truly appreciate it! I am assembling my thesis. Here is my main.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\graphicspath{{./Chapters/Figures/}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Load math package
\usepackage{amsmath}

%Set up the headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
%Allows first indent and loads setspace package to be used in different documents.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}

%Make cell space and scientific notation
\usepackage{longtable, cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = true}


%Enables paragraph spacing. Saves the old indent value and restores it after loading the parskip package. Otherwise, you lose the indents. 
\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\usepackage[sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Chapters/references.bib}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\input{Chapters/pageTitle.tex}

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\tableofcontents

% %Add chapters 
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{Chapters/Introduction.tex}

\chapter{Methodology}
\input{Chapters/Methodology.tex}

\chapter{Results}
\input{Chapters/Results.tex}

\chapter{Discussion}
\input{Chapters/Discussion.tex}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{Chapters/Conclusion.tex}

\appendix
\chapter{Figures}
\input{Chapters/Figures.tex}

\chapter{Tables}
\input{Chapters/Tables.tex}

\singlespacing
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

I am trying to add the abstract, acknowledgement, and contribution sections in Roman numerals before the introduction. I would like something like this in the table of contents:

```
Abstract.............II
Acknowledgement......III
Contribution.........IV
TableOfContents......V

Introduction.........1
....
```

I have seen similar posts about using the book class. However, I am using the report class. I don't know if changing class would affect anything. Is there a simple fix? Or an example using the report class? Thank you very much for you time!

EDIT:

```
   \documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
    \graphicspath{{./Chapters/Figures/}}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    %Load math package
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    %Set up the headers
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
    %Allows first indent and loads setspace package to be used in different documents.
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{url}

    %Make cell space and scientific notation
    \usepackage{longtable, cellspace, booktabs}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{scientific-notation = true}


    %Enables paragraph spacing. Saves the old indent value and restores it after loading the parskip package. Otherwise, you lose the indents. 
    \edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \restoreparindent

    \usepackage[sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{Chapters/references.bib}
    \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

    \usepackage{cleveref}

    \begin{document}

    \input{Chapters/titlePage.tex}
    \frontmatter
    \setcounter{page}{2}
    \chapter{Abstract}
    \input{Chapters/Abstract.tex}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc]{chapter}{Contents}

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \input{Chapters/Introduction.tex}

    \chapter{Methodology}
    \input{Chapters/Methodology.tex}

    \chapter{Results}
    \input{Chapters/Results.tex}

    \chapter{Discussion}
    \input{Chapters/Discussion.tex}

    \chapter{Conclusion}
    \input{Chapters/Conclusion.tex}

    \appendix
    \chapter{Figures}
    \input{Chapters/Figures.tex}

    \chapter{Tables}
    \input{Chapters/Tables.tex}

    \singlespacing
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

    \end{document}
```

which gives me:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just switching to `book`? These are both standard classes so there should not be too many surprises and you can easily switch back if you have problems. `book` is really more suited to what you want to do here.

Comment: Note that you won't get things like `Abstract` in the ToC unless your document actually contains them!

Comment: @Bernard `report.cls` doesn't define those, does it? (I mean `\frontmatter` etc. Of course `\pagenumbering` is fine.) At least, the copy on my machine doesn't.

Comment: @cfr: I should have checked. I guessed I got confused becaus I patched report for that long ago. Thanks for pointing it. I'll replace my comment.

Comment: You can write `\pagenumbering{Roman}` before inputting the abstract, then `\pagenumbering{arabic}` before inputting the introduction (maybe adding a `\clearpage` command).

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your input! Could you please look at my edit? I am almost there! :) Essentially, I would like to remove blank pages after each section and include "table of contents" within the table of contents.

Comment: @Bernard Oups! I figured it out! :D

Comment: I'll look at it, but you really want to learn *where* is that damned table of contents from the table of contents? :o)

Comment: @Bernard hahaha I know... It's just that theses from my biochemistry department use that style, and my department is quite conservative! lol

Comment: For the blank pages after chapters (I think it's not after sections), I guess the class option `openany` should fo the trick. As for  self-adding the table of contents, something like `\addcontentsline{toc]{chapter}{Contents}` right after `\tableofcontents` should do the trick.

Comment: Are you printing double-sided or single? If single, add `oneside` to the package options. You don't need `openany` in this case, either.

Comment: @Bernard Hi! I have re-edited my code, but I still have the issue with the integrated "Contents"

Comment: @cfr Hi! I realized it! It was such a simple fix! lol

Comment: Did you compile twice after adding the code @Bernard suggested to get the ToC in the ToC?

Comment: @cfr I am using sharelatex. Shouldn't it do it?

Comment: I'd expect so but I'm not sure I've never used it. If stuff usually gets added to the ToC on first compilation, probably it takes care of rerunning it for you.

Comment: Is there any news here? I am not even sure what the question is.